# Sent 'pure' JSON instead of multiform with jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

When I send a JSON object with jQuery Ajax it is seen as 'multiform' instead of a pure JSON object. How do I sent a pure JSON request instead of a multiform?

```
var demo = new Array("One", "Two", "Three"); 

$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  url : "http://domain.nl/api/v1/endpoint",
  type: "POST",
  dataType : "json",
  data: { data: JSON.stringify(demo) },
  success : function(callback){

  },
  error : function(callback){

  }
});
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "multiform." Your request will have a single parameter, called `data`, that will be a JSON string that represents your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `contentType: 'application/json'` property to the ajax request options.

Comment: and just use `data: JSON.stringify(demo)` without the additional object wrapper.

Comment: Thanks! Did the trick. The right way to capture the data on the server is: `$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input', true));`